# Using REST api and oAuth2 with iOS app

Tags: ios, rest, oauth

I'm a complete beginner in RESTful services in general. I am required to make an app that would require a user to log in with his credentials and then use the oAuth token to access the provided api.

I registered the app that I made and I have the Client ID and Client secret.
Now I have two questions:
How should the URI look like when I try to get the oAuth token?
What is the redirect uri used for?

Comment: A good place to start would be here:  https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749

Comment: Thank you @DaImTo ! From the documentation: "The resource owner password credentials (i.e., username and password) can be used directly as an authorization grant to obtain an access  token." How do I get the token when I have the username and password in the way the documentations says?